# onMapLongClick() not creating custom marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

I am trying to implement a code which creates custom markers on long press,however the long press doesnt create any marker

```
override fun onMapLongClick(latLng: LatLng) {
       addMarker(latLng)
        addCircle(latLng,GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
    }
    
    private fun addMarker(latLng: LatLng) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }
    private fun addCircle(latLng: LatLng, radius: Double){
        val circleOptions = CircleOptions()
        circleOptions.center(latLng)
        circleOptions.radius(radius)
        circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255,255,0,0))
        circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(64,255,0,0))
        circleOptions.strokeWidth(4F)
        mMap.addCircle(circleOptions)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a Build Version check?
Did you do a permission check?

try using

```
    mMap.clear()
```

first thing in the onMapLongClick method